# Hight performance web server specifications

Tags: php, android, apache, webserver, cloud

Please I apologize if my question is not appropriate, but I truly need answer. I'm working on a web application that suppose to be used in an environment where the traffic is very hight, and I want to know which server specifications will be better like DBMS(currently MySQL), CPU, Memory, architecture... Mark, or what ever..., because I'm a newbie in that domain. Indeed, the web app will be used in the following situations:

- **Almost 50 000 people suppose to send data from their mobile app  (Android client) through an API** to the Web App (host on the Server) within a few time's scope (around one hours). It's most probable that most of those people (50% to 80%) send the data at the same time.
- **The server will receive web request in GET method to be deliver for a browser (every 10 seconds)** and the request will require so many computational resource in term of software in order to deliver some statistic results based on the data sent from the mobile...
- **The Web App is build with the php Framwork Symfony2**

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server design/configuration is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify which cloud you want to use (if u want to use obviously)
AWS or Azure you can use. As per flow from clients your IaaS can be autoscale here. 
EG: If you use Azure then I will suggest use your software dependencies which you know better on A4 or D4 size VM.
Refer:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-size-specs/
[Azure VM size]

You can use Azure API service or Azure mobile App service but as you mentioned that you like to have hosted on server so go for virtual machines.

Pros: You can scale VM as per need (size). You have to pay only for you use (cloud property)

Thanks.

Comment: I've not plan to use any third party service all the resource have to be completely private on a private server so please update your response if it's possible.

Comment: In terms of private server, you can use certain specification like 2 core 4 GB ram initially. Because ideally what exact memory/CPU amount is utilized by your app and other processes can affect this. So you have to monitor and as per response we can increase and decrease specification.
Note: it may cause interruption on peak load (use autoscaling/loadbalancing)